# Python - adding datetime column to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, python-dateutil

I have a huge number of excel files i need to extract data from, hopefully into a pandas df.  The file contains a number of columns, one of which is time as a string like "16:30"

The filenames are "Monday 21st September 2020.xlsx" for example

I'm trying to loop through the files, and add a datetime column that includes the date from the filename, and the time from the column in the excel file.  I've tried the following with the loop limited to one file

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import dateutil
import glob
import pathlib

folder = r"C:\temp\Friday 1st April 2022 (SB).xlsx"

for file in glob.glob(folder, recursive=False):
    #read in the excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="SB", usecols="B,I,J")
    
    #workout the date from the file name
    filedate = dateutil.parser.parse(pathlib.Path(file).stem.replace(" (SB)",""))
    
    #print filedate because it doesnt end up in the df correctly!
    print(type(filedate))
    print(filedate)
    df.insert(0,'Date', racedate.strftime('%d-$m-%Y'))
  
    print(df)
```

And that gives, this.....  So the date add to the df is going wrong somewhere

```
C:\temp\Friday 1st April 2022 (SB).xlsx
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
2022-04-01 00:00:00
           Date   Time  R1  R2
0    01-$m-2022  16:30   9   5
1    01-$m-2022  16:30   5   5
2    01-$m-2022  16:30   6   5
3    01-$m-2022  16:30   3   6
4    01-$m-2022  16:30   3   3
..          ...    ...  ..  ..
446  01-$m-2022  16:15   3   4
447  01-$m-2022  16:15   3   3
448  01-$m-2022  16:15   3   3
449  01-$m-2022  16:15   5   3
450  01-$m-2022  16:15   5   4

[451 rows x 4 columns]
```

Also once i get this sorted i want to merge the two Date and Time columns into one datetime object.

Comment: It looks like you've just accidentally put a `$M` in your string format instead of `%M`, hence the $M output. I think correcting that should give you your desired output for the day column

Comment: I just realised that too, I've changed to %m and it's made no difference so i have edited the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the date from the `folder` variable like this.

```
from dateutil import parser
import re 

folder = r"C:\temp\Friday 1st April 2022 (SB).xlsx"

date_string = re.findall(r'\d{1,2}[a-z]{2} \w+ \d{4}', folder)[0]
date_obj = parser.parse(date_string)
print(date_obj.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))
```

This will print `01-04-2022`

The `date_string` variable is calculated by regex and you get it as `1st April 2022` which the dateutil library can easily parse then.

**Regex explanation:**

`\d{1,2}`: one or two digits to match the day of month number

`[a-z]{2}`: two lowercase letters to match the "st", "nd" and "rd"

`\w+`: one or more word characters to match the month name

`\d{4}`: four digits to match the year number

With the above, you can get the `1st April 2022` from the whole path.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that the folder will in reality end in *.xlsx not a file name. The loop below will then loop through the files adding the correct date column for each file each time.

Comment: Then instead of the `folder` use the `file` instead the loop.

Comment: Of course! Thanks, I'll give this a try, not that I understand the regex lol

Comment: @ChrisLewis I added a regex explanation. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: That's very clear. Thanks!